# Assigning a value out of array of arrays, using section in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

This my code:

```
let serviceBonnen = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] //not real data


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = serviceBonnen[section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

But it gives me an error at the "section" point in this line of code:

```
cell.textLabel!.text = serviceBonnen[section][indexPath.row]
```

Does anybody know why this won't compile, and what would be a proper solution?

Comment: You need to read the error message, or at least give it to us. @Miknash did you find it, but usually we can help you understand the error message if you didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `section` from `indexPath` :

```
indexPath.section
```

Your line should look like this:

```
cell.textLabel!.text = serviceBonnen[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```